# Good source on current 'views and thoughts' on mathematics

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, meta-math

Recently I've become interested in the history of the way people think about mathematics. What I mean by this is for example how Godels proof basically put an end to the whole school of thought proposed by Bertrand Russel.

Now I wonder if there are any similar 'schools of thought' in current mathematics. And if there are any good sources on the complete history of how all those views and schools of thought came to be and how they ended.

Comment: Godels proof basically _should have_ put an end to the whole school of thought
proposed by Bertrand Russel. But it didn't.
[Mathematical Formalism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Formalism_(mathematics)),
as promoted by Hilbert, is Russel and Whitehead in disguise. And it hasn't
come to an end. On the contrary: it's the mainstream in nowadays
mathematics. Simply use the "delete" button in a discipline seems to be
problematic, once so much work has been done.

Comment: [Now cross-posted on HSM](http://hsm.stackexchange.com/questions/690/good-source-on-current-views-and-thoughts-on-mathematics), which is not a good thing.

Comment: @CarlMummert Hm I have no idea what you mean by that.

Comment: Perhaps it is just the way that the question is phrased (this may also be why there are not many answers). It seems to me the question is more philosophical than mathematical - and such questions often attract users who want to express their own opinions. @user2520938

Comment: @CarlMummert Oke that I can kind of understand. How would you suggest the question to be rephrased in order to make it better while still asking for the same information?

Comment: That I am not sure about - most of the rephrasings I can think of only make the question seem more philosophical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For the "foundational" debate of the '30s, see :

- Marcus Giaquinto, [The Search for Certainty : A Philosophical Account of Foundations of Mathematics](https://books.google.it/books?id=gyNbrpYXzxoC&printsec=frontcover) (2002).

For some impact on mathematics of one of the above philosophical "schools" (e.g. [Intuitionism](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intuitionism/) and related : [Intuitionistic Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/logic-intuitionistic/), [The Development of Intuitionistic Logic](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/intuitionistic-logic-development/), [Luitzen Egbertus Jan Brouwer](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/brouwer/), [Set Theory: Constructive and Intuitionistic ZF](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory-constructive/)) see [Constructive Mathematics](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/mathematics-constructive/) and :

- Errett Bishop, [Foundations of Constructive Analysis](https://books.google.it/books?id=G4OBMQEACAAJ) (1st ed 1967).

---

It is also worth noting a "connection" between Intuitionism/Constructivism, Alonzo Church's [Lambda Calculus](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/lambda-calculus/) and [N.G. de Bruijn](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nicolaas_Govert_de_Bruijn)'s [Automath](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automath) (and see [here](http://www.win.tue.nl/automath/archive/pdf/aut029.pdf)), a formal language "precursor" of proof assistants.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think this is more along the line of what I'm looking for. I will check it out in detail later tonight.

Comment: Some further relevant references w.r.t. constructivism:
[Constructivism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructivism_(mathematics)) ;
[Intuitionism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intuitionism) ;
[L. E. J. Brouwer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L._E._J._Brouwer) .

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are interested in what is often called *philosophy of mathematics*. While there are many books and articles on this subject out there, I can personally recommend Shapiro's [Thinking About Mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0192893068), which takes the reader through an introduction to both the history of the philosophy of mathematics, as well as more recent ideas and schools of thought.

Comment: Hm that seems a bit too philosophy-y for me. I did find 'Mathematics: The Loss of Certainty' though. Do you know it? It seems a bit less 'general philosophy' and more math focussed.